# Combine Rows but concatenate on a certain field in Excel Power Query or Microsoft SQL

Tags: sql, excel, powerquery

I have brought a table from an Authority database into Excel via power query OBDC type, that includes fields like:

1. Date - various
2. **Comments** - mem_txt
3. Sequence - seq_num

The **Comments** field has a length restriction, and if a longer string is entered, it returns multiple rows with the **Comments**  field being chopped into suitable lengths and the order returned in the **Sequence** field as per extract below.  All other parts of the records are the same.
[image]

I want to collapse the rows based and concatenate the various **Comments** into a single entry. There is a date/time column just outside of the screen shot above that can be used to group the rows by (it is the same for the set of rows, but unique across the data set).

For example:
[image]

I did try bring the data in by a query connection, using the GROUP_CONCAT(**Comments** SEPARATOR ', ') and GROUP BY date, but that command isn't available in Microsoft Query.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the date/time column you refer to is named `date_time`, the M code would be:

```
let
  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name = "Table1"]}[Content], 
  #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(
    Source, 
    {"date_time"}, 
    {{"NewCol", each Text.Combine([mem_text])}}
  )
in
  #"Grouped Rows"
```

Amend the `Source` line as required.